# How to detect availability of previous/next page in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I understand that Selenium's WebDriver has some methods to navigate backwards/forwards in the browser.

Back:
`driver.Navigate().Back();`
Forward:
`driver.Navigate().Forward();`

Now I would like to check if these methods do lead to an available page, **before** actually clicking the buttons (in your browser, the arrows are either bold or light grey).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going back you can check the length of the history with a JavaScript call:

```
//Java:
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
bool has_history = js.executeScript("return window.history.length > 0;");

//C#:
bool has_history = driver.ExecuteScript("return window.history.length > 0;");
```

And for the forward calls, I would just keep track of the back calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did help. I think you haven't noticed the C# tag on the question, you seem to have answered in another language. In C# `IJavaScriptExecutor` is used as executor. Also, in my solution I have used an extension method to fetch this executor (this is not required).